# How to randomly assign variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hello I am trying to make a simple multiple choice quiz in pygame. This is the code I wrote and it works as intended.

```
from random import choice
qUsed=[]
qEasy = [
    {
        "question": "What year is it",
        "choices": {"a": "2009", "b": "2016", "c": "2010"},
        "answer": "b"
    },
    {
        "question": "Another Question",
        "choices": {"a": "choice 1", "b": "choice 2", "c": "choice 3"},
        "answer": "a"
    },
    {
        "question": "Another Question",
        "choices": {"a": "choice 1", "b": "choice 2", "c": "choice 3"},
        "answer": "a"
    },
    {
        "question": "Another Question",
        "choices": {"a": "choice 1", "b": "choice 2", "c": "choice 3"},
        "answer": "a"
    },
    {
        "question": "Another Question",
        "choices": {"a": "choice 1", "b": "choice 2", "c": "choice 3"},
        "answer": "a"
    }
]

def Quiz(qLevel):
    global qUsed
    if qLevel == []: # if qLevel becomes empty
        qLevel = qUsed # dump everything from qUsed to qLevel
        qUsed = [] # reset qUsed to an empty list
    x = choice(qLevel) # assign x to a random question in qLevel
    print(x.get('question')) # print the question
    answer = input(x.get('choices')).lower() # print the choices

    if answer == x.get('answer'): # if answer is correct
        print("You got it")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
    qLevel.remove(x) # remove used question from list
    qUsed.append(x) # add it to an empty unused list (qUsed)

Quiz(qEasy)
Quiz(qEasy)
```

The problem arises here when I wrote a pygame script to open a window with the question as a header and the three possible answers randomly blitted on three black rectangles. What I want to do is to randomly pick a question from the list, blit it on the screen where it says "Insert question here" and randomly assign answers to the three rectangles. If you were to press the right rectangle then the rectangle changes colour to green, otherwise, it becomes red. But I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
def Screen():
mouse.set_visible(1)
clock = time.Clock()
# The button is just a rect.
A1 = Rect(30, 100, 175, 250)
A2 = Rect(230, 100, 175, 250)
A3 = Rect(430, 100, 175, 250)

while True:

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    draw.rect(screen, BLACK, A1)
    draw.rect(screen, BLACK, A2)
    draw.rect(screen, BLACK, A3)

    Question_surf = FONT.render(("Insert Question Here"), True, BLACK)
    A1_surf = FONT.render(("Answer 1"), True, WHITE)
    A2_surf = FONT.render(("Answer 2"), True, WHITE)
    A3_surf = FONT.render(("Answer 3"), True, WHITE)

    A1_rect = A1_surf.get_rect(center=(120, 225))
    A2_rect = A2_surf.get_rect(center=(320,225))
    A3_rect = A3_surf.get_rect(center=(520,225))
    Question_rect = Question_surf.get_rect(center=(320, 50))

    screen.blit(A1_surf, A1_rect)
    screen.blit(A2_surf, A2_rect)
    screen.blit(A3_surf, A3_rect)
    screen.blit(Question_surf, Question_rect)

    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            exit("Exit")
        # This block is executed once for each MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event.
        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # 1 is the left mouse button, 2 is middle, 3 is right.
            if e.button == 1:
                # `event.pos` is the mouse position.
                if A1.collidepoint(e.pos):
                    pass
                elif A2.collidepoint(e.pos):
                    pass
                elif A3.collidepoint(e.pos):
                    pass

    display.update()

    clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   Screen()
```

Comment: So? What is the problem?

Comment: @Psytho problem is I can’t figure out how to do it

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] of your problem people are more likely to help you. Nobody wants to skim over pages of code just to figure out what's actually bothering you...

Comment: @zwer I shortened it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle through the questions I'd define an `index` variable and assign the current question-choices-answer dict to a variable (I just call it `question` here).

```
questions = qEasy
random.shuffle(questions)
index = 0
question = questions[index]
```

Increment the index when the user switches to the next `question` (I'd do that in the event loop).

```
index += 1
if index >= len(questions):
    # Reset everything or show a game over screen.
    index = 0
question = questions[index]
```

Pass the question text and choices to `font.render` (you can render the texts only once when they need to be updated).

```
Question_surf = FONT.render(question["question"], True, BLACK)
A1_surf = FONT.render(question["choices"]["a"], True, WHITE)
# etc.
```

When the user clicks on a button, check if the corresponding answer is correct and then change the color of the button/rect.

```
if A1.collidepoint(e.pos):
    if question["answer"] == "a":
        A1_color = GREEN
    else:
        A1_color = RED
```

Pass the current rect color to `pygame.draw.rect`.

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, A1_color, A1)
```

When the user switches to the next question, reset the button colors.

Answer (score -1):

Lists are a very nice method of being able to have random answers.

You would first go into a ranged for loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    myList.append(answers['Your question'][random.randint(0, 3)])
```

Then you can index the new list when you need to draw

`text = myFont.render(myList[0], True, (255, 255, 255))`

Later you might want to add some duplicate-detecting code but i hope this helps.

Comment: Ranged `for` loops are _last_ thing you do in Python, only if there is no other way to express something without unnecessary index values.  This looks like a job for `random.shuffle()`.